# Why does the Name Property of FileInfo object start with "~$"?

Tags: c#, .net, xlsx, fileinfo, directoryinfo

So I'm writing some code that is going through a directory of `.xlsx` files and picking the file that was created last. It's a simple task, but there is something a bit strange happening with the `Name` property of a particular `FileInfo` object and potentially there are more cases of this occurring.

Here is my code:

```
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(FolderPath);
        FileInfo[] FileArray = di.GetFiles("*.xlsx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        if (FileArray.Count() != 0) 
        {
            DateTime latestDate = DateTime.MinValue;
            string FileName = String.Empty;
            foreach (FileInfo File in FileArray)
            {
                if (File.CreationTime > latestDate)
                {
                    latestDate = File.CreationTime;
                    FileName = File.FullName;  
                }
            }
        }
```

The `FileName` is important because I use it to query the latest file for information and display it. However, the `Name` property of a particular .xlsx file (potentially more) is appearing like this `~$File.xlsx` when in fact the file name is really `File.xlsx`. This causes the `FullName` property to contain these characters as well.

Is there any way to fix this? What triggers this?

Comment: Microsoft office tools like excel and work create temporary files beginning with ~$. I think these files exists in your folder and File class is just showing that information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opening an xlsx file results in Excel creating a hidden file with the same name preceded by "~$". So if one of these Excel files are open at the time you retrieve the content of the directory, you will also get the temp file.

Add a filter that excludes hidden files and your issue is fixed.

Example:

```
FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(path);

if((attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden)
{
    // Hidden file, just skip it
}
```

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getattributes.aspx

Comment: Would something like `File.Name.Contains("~$")` be effective?

Comment: @DerekW: I would use the example I provided, this way you make sure no hidden files are served, which might help avoid other issues as well.

Answer (score 1):

`~$` indicates that the file is a temporary file used by Microsoft Office. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/405257/what-type-of-file-is-file) for additional information.